# How can I find out what my control port is?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm trying to use Tor in conjunction with FrostWire, and I' following these instructions:

http://www.ehow.com/how_7510294_do-configure-tor-frostwire.html

I can't seem to figure out how to get the control port, as there doesn't seem to be any such thing in settings > advanced.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

It is generally port 9151.  If you go to the browser directory, go under Data, then under Tor, look for the torrc-defaults file.  It will say something like

ControlPort 9151

Answer (score 0):

Mine is 9150 I think.. I couldn't find it in the torrc defaults file, but I found out by going to the dropdown menu in the upper right corner of the Tor browser. Then in the section "General" (left side), scroll all the way down. There under the tab "Network Proxy" you click on Settings... And there you see the port it is listening to, I think? Or is a "Control port" something different?